# elasticsearch command error

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.0

I have installed elastic search in ubuntu. using this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RFw9j4ihag&t=27s)

but when I run this command `"sudo systemctl start elasticsearch"`

I get the below error.

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

then I run this command `systemctl status elasticsearch.service`
I get below error

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2020-12-17 17:43:29 IST; 28min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 93868 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=143)
   Main PID: 93868 (code=exited, status=143)

Dec 17 17:42:12 rushikesh systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Dec 17 17:43:28 rushikesh systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dec 17 17:43:29 rushikesh systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 17 17:43:29 rushikesh systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

then I run this command `journalctl -xe`
and I get below error,

```
Dec 17 17:30:28 rushikesh /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1974]: See https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.15.5/touchpad-jumping-cursors>
Dec 17 17:30:32 rushikesh dbus-daemon[823]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' req>
Dec 17 17:30:32 rushikesh systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
-- Subject: A start job for unit fprintd.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit fprintd.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 15769.
Dec 17 17:30:32 rushikesh PackageKit[90821]: daemon quit
Dec 17 17:30:32 rushikesh systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit packagekit.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Dec 17 17:30:33 rushikesh dbus-daemon[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Dec 17 17:30:33 rushikesh systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit fprintd.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit fprintd.service has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 15769.
Dec 17 17:30:34 rushikesh gdm-password][91752]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Dec 17 17:30:41 rushikesh gdm-password][91752]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Dec 17 17:30:41 rushikesh gdm-password][91752]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Dec 17 17:30:41 rushikesh NetworkManager[824]: <info>  [1608206441.8908] agent-manager: agent[e037d5e0796523ba,:1.95/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkA>
Dec 17 17:30:41 rushikesh dbus-daemon[1895]: [session uid=1000 pid=1895] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by >
Dec 17 17:30:42 rushikesh dbus-daemon[1895]: [session uid=1000 pid=1895] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.44' (u>
Dec 17 17:30:44 rushikesh dbus-daemon[1895]: [session uid=1000 pid=1895] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Dec 17 17:30:44 rushikesh org.gnome.Nautilus[91789]: Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
```

how can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need to increase the timeout of the ElasticSearch service.

run the command:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full elasticsearch.service
```

Set the `TimeoutStartSec` to `900`

`TimeoutStartSec=900`

Read more details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value)